# scroll bar should be at bootom without setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to keep my scroll bar each time user send or receive a new message .

```
<script>
$ = jQuery;
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var scrolled;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
     }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#chatbox").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      if(!scrolled){
      $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
      scrolled=true;
      }
    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

 fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
      scrolled=false;
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    fetch_chat();
});



  $("#sub").click(function() {

    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
      scrolled=false;
      setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();}, 500);
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

what I want is that whenever a user send or receive a new message the scroll  bar should come to bottom but it should be scrollable according to user's desire. the setinterval() bring the scroll bar down whenever its scrolled up .
I want to call the fetch_chat() repeatedly but not the scroll bar ,I want it to be at bottom : at the beginning,after sending or receiving a new message and must be scrollable freely.

Comment: Compare the current chat HTML with the previous chat HTML, and if they are different, then scroll, if they are the same, then don't.

Comment: how to compare that???

Comment: Added my answer.  If you could please mark as solution / upvote (if it is the solution), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic logic of the following answer:

> Compare the current chat HTML with the previous chat HTML, and if they are different, then scroll, if they are the same, then don't.

```
<script>
$ = jQuery;
var currentID = null,
    chatTimer = null,
    oldHtml = "";

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
     }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#chatbox").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      if (oldHtml !== data) {
        $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
      }
      oldHtml = data;
    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

 fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    fetch_chat();
});



  $("#sub").click(function() {

    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
      setInterval(fetch_chat, 500);
    });
  });

});
</script>
```